# Android autoLink cause render error

Tags: android

I've got some problems with autoLink="phone" option of TextView.
My UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/personPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:text="test" />
</TableLayout>
```

When i switching to Graphical Layout (in ADT) im getting following error:
    Exception raised during rendering: com/android/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil
    Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
    The following classes could not be found:
    - TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Error in log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil
    at android.text.util.Linkify.gatherTelLinks(Linkify.java:451)
    at android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(Linkify.java:230)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3700)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3622)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1259)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:607)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor16.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:86)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3028)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

If i remove

```
android:autoLink="phone"
```

error disappears.

Also if i change "phone" to "email", there wouldn't any errors, but "all" cause the same error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have the same behavior when i use API level 18 to render the view. It won't affect your program. As a workaround you can change the "API version to use when rendering in Eclipse" to 16 rather than 18 while working with layouts that include autolink. There is a button above the graphical view with a robot icon and a number which you can use to change that.

This bug also occurs in Android Studio and is being tracked in Android's issue tracker at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59497.

Comment: yeap, I'm installed API 16 with SDK Manager, switched rendering layout API and that works well now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution. you can use 
tools: name space to override android name space for example you can use next code sample

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

          <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="all"
                tools:autoLink="none"
                />
```

You need only that **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"** and **tools:autoLink="none"**
This will be applyed only for preview rendering, you cant found that attributes on runtime

Also you can use that name space for other attributes, for ex.:

```
tools:text="Some text that visible only on preview"
```